# HTML, CSS, display

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the CSS specifications on http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/matt_black_tabs/.

I tried to understand what difference and why put those properties just at the `li` and the `a` elements.  What if the display was inline or block? I have tried to close some styles to see how it looks and I can't understand it.

Why is the display on the `li` and `a` elements set to `inline` and `block`? What would happen without those specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display property tells what style you want your object arranged. When you use block style it displays it like paragraphs and headers. Inline is default and has no line break before or after it. For more information on display go to
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/display/

Comment: Though I'm NOT the downvoter, still since you have put a w3schools link, did u take a look at [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com) ?

Comment: I never knew W3schools is a bad site, what are some better sources?

Comment: [HTMLDog](http://htmldog.com/), [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/) are much better than W3Schools.

Comment: @DrinkJavaCodeJava We've collected some other ressources over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744906/would-you-recommend-starting-from-html5-css3-for-beginners/4746056#4746056